# message passing not occuring in mpi in c

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int npes,myrank,arr[400],i,data,flag=0,a[2],b[2],c[2];
    MPI_Request req;
    MPI_Status status,status1,status2;
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&npes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);  
        //printf("dada");
        for(i=0;i<400;i++){ 
            //printf("dhsddn");
            if(i==387){
                arr[i]=11;
                continue;
            }
            arr[i]=rand()%11;
        }
    /*for(i=385;i<400;i++){
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }*/

    //printf("gggggg");
    //MPI_Bcast(&arr,400,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    //printf("stsaege");
    if(myrank==0){
        MPI_Irecv(&a,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);

        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            //printf("myrank0");
//          MPI_Irecv(&a,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
            MPI_Test(&req,&flag,&status);
            //printf("(%d)",flag);
            if(flag){
                MPI_Recv(&b,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status1);
                MPI_Recv(&c,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status2);
                /*printf*/
                printf("(0)\t0\t%d\n",i);
                printf("(%d)\t%d\t%d\n",status.MPI_SOURCE,a[0],a[1]);
                printf("(%d)\t%d\t%d\n",status1.MPI_SOURCE,b[0],b[1]);
                printf("(%d)\t%d\t%d\n",status2.MPI_SOURCE,c[0],c[1]);
                break;
            }
            else if(arr[i]==11){
                data=1;
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,1,110,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//1
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,2,110,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//2
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,3,110,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//3
                MPI_Recv(&b,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status1);
                MPI_Recv(&c,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status2);
                MPI_Recv(&a,2,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
                /*send message -1 to rest oof the three*/
                /*print results*/
                printf("(0)\t1\t%d\n",i);
                printf("(%d)\t%d\t%d\n",status.MPI_SOURCE,a[0],a[1]);
                printf("(%d)\t%d\t%d\n",status1.MPI_SOURCE,b[0],b[1]);
                printf("(%d)\t%d\t%d\n",status2.MPI_SOURCE,c[0],c[1]);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(myrank==1){
        MPI_Irecv(&data,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);

        for(i=100;i<200;i++){
            //printf("myrank1");
//          MPI_Irecv(&data,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
            MPI_Test(&req,&flag,&status);
            if(flag){
                a[0]=0;
                a[1]=i;
                MPI_Send(a,2,MPI_INT,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                break;
            }
            else if(arr[i]==11){
                a[0]=1;
                a[1]=i;
                data=1;
                MPI_Send(a,2,MPI_INT,0,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//0
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,2,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//2
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,3,10,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//3

                /*send message -1 to rest oof the three*/
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(myrank==2){
        MPI_Irecv(&data,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);

        for(i=200;i<300;i++){
            //printf("myrank2");
//          MPI_Irecv(&data,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
            MPI_Test(&req,&flag,&status);
            if(flag!=0){
                a[0]=0;
                a[1]=i;
                MPI_Send(a,2,MPI_INT,0,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                break;
            }
            else if(arr[i]==11){
                a[0]=1;
                a[1]=i;
                data=1;
                MPI_Send(a,2,MPI_INT,0,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//0
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,1,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//1
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,3,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//3

                /*send message -1 to rest oof the three*/
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(myrank==3){
        MPI_Irecv(&data,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);

        for(i=300;i<400;i++){
            //printf("myrank3");
//          MPI_Irecv(&data,1,MPI_INT,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req);
            MPI_Test(&req,&flag,&status);
            //printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
            if(flag!=0){
                            //printf("khdfff");

                a[0]=0;
                a[1]=i;
                MPI_Send(a,2,MPI_INT,0,30,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                break;
            }
            else if(arr[i]==11){
            //printf("khdf");
                a[0]=1;
                a[1]=i;
                data=1;
                printf("im in");
                MPI_Send(a,2,MPI_INT,0,30,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//0
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,1,30,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//1
                MPI_Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,2,30,MPI_COMM_WORLD);//2

                /*send message -1 to rest oof the three*/
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
}
/*-1->>some process has found it || flag not equal to zero */
/*a[0]-->0-not found
a[1]-->index*/
```

this code tries for number 11 in an array of 400 elements using 4 processes. i have set 11 at index 387.so according to code process no 3(ie process 4) should return the index of 11 while all others should return current index they are searching. I my irecv is never getting message from proc no. 3. the flag value always is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to dig into all of your code since it's quite long and I'm not sure from your explanation what you're trying to do exactly. However, it's pretty obvious by glancing through it that your sends and receives are not matched up. Remember that for every call to `MPI_Send` (or `MPI_Isend`, etc.), you need to have a matching call to `MPI_Recv` (or `MPI_Irecv`, etc.). It looks like you have lots of sends that happen in a lop but only about one receive per process. Make sure you match these up.